# Blazor Chart.js 2.0.2 raises onClick error

Tags: chart.js, blazor, blazor-webassembly

I'm trying to create a stacked bar chart with `Clartjs.Blazor` version 2.0.2. After a long research, I found the [source code](https://github.com/mariusmuntean/ChartJs.Blazor/releases) of this library.

The application is a Blazor WebAssembly. So, I added in the *index.html*

```
<script src="lib/moment.js/moment.js"></script>
<script src="lib/Chart.js/chart.js"></script>
<script src="_content/ChartJs.Blazor.Fork/ChartJsBlazorInterop.js"></script>
```

In the page I added the graph

```
@page "/"
@using ChartJs.Blazor.BarChart
@using ChartJs.Blazor.BarChart.Axes
@using System.Drawing
@using System.Collections.Generic
@using System.Collections.ObjectModel

<Chart Config="_config" @ref="_chart"></Chart>

<button @onclick="RandomizeData">Randomize Data</button>

@code { private const int InitalCount = 7;
    private BarConfig _config;
    private Chart _chart;

    protected override void OnInitialized()
    {
        _config = new BarConfig
        {
            Options = new BarOptions
            {
                Responsive = true,
                Title = new OptionsTitle
                {
                    Display = true,
                    Text = "Chart.js Bar Chart - Stacked"
                },
                Tooltips = new Tooltips
                {
                    Mode = InteractionMode.Index,
                    Intersect = false
                },
                Scales = new BarScales
                {
                    XAxes = new List<CartesianAxis>
                {
                        new BarCategoryAxis
                        {
                            Stacked = true
                        }
                    },
                    YAxes = new List<CartesianAxis>
                {
                        new BarLinearCartesianAxis
                        {
                            Stacked = true
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        };

        IDataset<int> dataset1 = new BarDataset<int>(RandomScalingFactor(InitalCount))
        {
            Label = "Dataset 1",
            BackgroundColor = ColorUtil.FromDrawingColor(ChartColors.Red)
        };

        IDataset<int> dataset2 = new BarDataset<int>(RandomScalingFactor(InitalCount))
        {
            Label = "Dataset 2",
            BackgroundColor = ColorUtil.FromDrawingColor(ChartColors.Blue)
        };

        IDataset<int> dataset3 = new BarDataset<int>(RandomScalingFactor(InitalCount))
        {
            Label = "Dataset 3",
            BackgroundColor = ColorUtil.FromDrawingColor(ChartColors.Green)
        };

        _config.Data.Labels.AddRange(Months.Take(InitalCount));
        _config.Data.Datasets.Add(dataset1);
        _config.Data.Datasets.Add(dataset2);
        _config.Data.Datasets.Add(dataset3);
    }

    private void RandomizeData()
    {
        foreach (IDataset<int> dataset in _config.Data.Datasets)
        {
            int count = dataset.Count;
            dataset.Clear();
            dataset.AddRange(RandomScalingFactor(count));
        }

        _chart.Update();
    }

    private static readonly Random _rng = new Random();

    public static class ChartColors
    {
        private static readonly Lazy<IReadOnlyList<Color>> _all = new Lazy<IReadOnlyList<Color>>(() => new Color[7]
        {
                Red, Orange, Yellow, Green, Blue, Purple, Grey
            });

        public static IReadOnlyList<Color> All => _all.Value;

        public static readonly Color Red = Color.FromArgb(255, 99, 132);
        public static readonly Color Orange = Color.FromArgb(255, 159, 64);
        public static readonly Color Yellow = Color.FromArgb(255, 205, 86);
        public static readonly Color Green = Color.FromArgb(75, 192, 192);
        public static readonly Color Blue = Color.FromArgb(54, 162, 235);
        public static readonly Color Purple = Color.FromArgb(153, 102, 255);
        public static readonly Color Grey = Color.FromArgb(201, 203, 207);
    }

    public static IReadOnlyList<string> Months { get; } = new ReadOnlyCollection<string>(new[]
    {
            "January", "February", "March", "April", "May", "June", "July", "August", "September", "October", "November", "December"
        });

    private static int RandomScalingFactorThreadUnsafe() => _rng.Next(-100, 100);

    public static int RandomScalingFactor()
    {
        lock (_rng)
        {
            return RandomScalingFactorThreadUnsafe();
        }
    }

    public static IEnumerable<int> RandomScalingFactor(int count)
    {
        int[] factors = new int[count];
        lock (_rng)
        {
            for (int i = 0; i < count; i++)
            {
                factors[i] = RandomScalingFactorThreadUnsafe();
            }
        }

        return factors;
    }

    public static IEnumerable<DateTime> GetNextDays(int count)
    {
        DateTime now = DateTime.Now;
        DateTime[] factors = new DateTime[count];
        for (int i = 0; i < factors.Length; i++)
        {
            factors[i] = now.AddDays(i);
        }

        return factors;
    }
}
```

For future reference, this code should create the following graph. I found this code in [GitHub](https://github.com/mariusmuntean/ChartJs.Blazor/issues/87).

[image]

Obviously, it didn't work for me. When I run the application Blazor raises an error

> ```
>  crit: Microsoft.AspNetCore.Components.WebAssembly.Rendering.WebAssemblyRenderer[100]
>
>  Unhandled exception rendering component: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'onClick')
>  TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'onClick')
>      at getDefaultFunc (https://localhost:44384/_content/ChartJs.Blazor.Fork/ChartJsBlazorInterop.js:75:116)
> ```

[image]

Is it only me that facing this issue? Is there a way to fix it?

Answer (score 1):

I had this same problem and it came down to the version of chart.js.
I was using chart.js v3.5.1.
When I switched to v2.9.4 the onClick was resolved.