# Integrate Blazor with Chart.js: how to pass an object

Tags: chart.js, blazor, blazor-webassembly

I want to display in my Blazor WebAssembly application, some graphs with `Chart.js`. I tried to use `Chartjs.Blazor.Fork` but I have few errors, for example I have opened another post about [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69372816/blazor-chart-js-2-0-2-raises-onclick-error).

So, after a day without results, I decided to start my own component. I follow the instruction I found in a [blog](https://www.puresourcecode.com/dotnet/blazor/using-chart-js-with-blazor/). Basically, I have my Razor component called `Chart.razor` with the following code

```
@inject IJSRuntime JSRuntime

<canvas id="@Id"></canvas>

@code {
    public enum ChartType
    {
        Pie,
        Bar
    }

    [Parameter]
    public string Id { get; set; }

    [Parameter]
    public ChartType Type { get; set; }

    [Parameter]
    public string[] Data { get; set; }

    [Parameter]
    public string[] BackgroundColor { get; set; }

    [Parameter]
    public string[] Labels { get; set; }

    protected override async Task OnAfterRenderAsync(bool firstRender)
    {
        // Here we create an anonymous type with all the options
        // that need to be sent to Chart.js
        var config = new
        {
            Type = Type.ToString().ToLower(),
            Options = new
            {
                Responsive = true,
                Scales = new
                {
                    YAxes = new[]
                    {
                        new { Ticks = new {
                            BeginAtZero=true
                        } }
                    }
                }
            },
            Data = new
            {
                Datasets = new[]
                {
                    new { Data = Data, BackgroundColor = BackgroundColor}
                },
                Labels = Labels
            }
        };

        await JSRuntime.InvokeVoidAsync("setup", Id, config);
    }
}
```

then I have my own `mychart.js` script to update the chart

```
window.setup = (id,config) => {
    var ctx = document.getElementById(id).getContext('2d');
    new Chart(ctx, config);
}
```

So, I use this code

```
<Chart Id="bar1" Type="@Chart.ChartType.Bar"
       Data="@(new[] { " 10", "9" } )"
       BackgroundColor="@(new[] { " yellow","red"} )"
       Labels="@(new[] { " Fail","Ok" } )">
</Chart>
```

Ugly code but it is working. Now, I can display a graph in my page. Cool! What I want to display is something more complex, because I have to show a stacked bar graph with groups and the configuration is quite complicated.

I want to replace the `config` you can see in the page with for example a class. In this class I want to collect all configuration, like `Type`, `Options`, `Data`, `Labels and so on, and pass them in the` await JSRuntime.InvokeVoidAsync("setup", Id, config);`

For starting I created my base class like

```
public abstract class ConfigBase
{
    protected ConfigBase(ChartType chartType)
    {
        Type = chartType;
    }

    public ChartType Type { get; }
    public string CanvasId { get; } = Guid.NewGuid().ToString();
}
```

My problem is how to transform this class to obtain a valid object for the JavaScript to execute correctly `new Chart(ctx, config);`.

Answer (score 1):

OK, it was quite easy. I saw a lot of different technics for that but there is a very basic simple way

```
await JSRuntime.InvokeVoidAsync("setup", Config.CanvasId, Config);
```